# PHP for loop unexpected (T_VARIABLE), expecting ';'

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I trying to write a regular loop for, but all the solution I've tried so far produce an error.

Both:

```
$length = count($fileList);

for ($index = 0; $index < $length; $index++) {
```

and

`for ($index = 0, $length = count($fileList); $index <= $length; $index++) {`

generate the following error (at compile time):

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$length' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\PC_administration_interface\Controler\Interface_builder\html\html_data_importer.php on line 590
```

If I try this:

```
for ($index = 0; $index < count($fileList); $index++) {
```

Then, I get this error (at runtime):

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function  count() in C:\xampp\htdocs\PC_administration_interface\Controler\Interface_builder\html\html_data_importer.php on line 590
```

Even that:

```
for ($index = 0; $index < 1; $index++) {
```

Give me the following error (at runtime):

```
Use of undefined constant  1 - assumed ' 1'
```

Here's the full context so far:

```
    /**
* In $fileList, validate the files (name and extension) and save the files related to the import.
* If a file already exists for a specific import, it will be replaced by the new one.
*
* @param $errorMessage String to return the error message.
* @param $fileList Array containing the files to upload. Use $_FILES[] and send the array of the upload button.
* @param $dataSource Int Use DataSupport class constant
* @param $cleanList Boolean clean the current list.
*/
public function saveSourceFileList(&$errorMessage, array $fileList, $dataSource, $cleanList = false){

    $errorMessage = "";

    $fileArray = array();

    $invalidArray = array();

    $path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../../Backup/';


    if (!empty($fileList)){

        $length = count($fileList);

        for ($index = 0; $index < $length; $index++) {

            if ($this->importer->isFileToImportValid($fileList['name'][$index], $dataSource)){

                $name = substr_replace($fileList['name'][$index], date("Ymd_His"), (strpos($fileList['name'][$index], ".")), 0);

                echo $name;

                $fileArray[] = "";
            }
            else{

                $invalidArray[] = $fileList['name'][$index];    
            }

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: OK, your second `for` is plain wrong. Let's go for the rest.

Comment: @PaulCrovella what do you mean?

Comment: The second loop is not wrong, check out at the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php It's the last entry before developpers comments.
Of and I haven't copy/paste from internet, I checked out at the dcumentation during 1 hours before asking...

Comment: But you are right Paul, the space seemed to be the error.